# Desktop web preview of iOS app on App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I've recently published an iOS app to the App Store, the link iTunesConnect provides me to 'View on App Store' is -  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/muzeroom/id1331957823?ls=1&mt=8

Unlike other apps, this doesn't show a 'App Store Preview' of what the listing looks like, instead it just tries to open iTunes.  What I was hoping was that it'd show something like this - https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/shazam/id284993459?mt=8

Any idea how I create one of these App Store Preview pages?  Without it, it's impossible to market this to iOS users who are browsing on desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is not available in the US store, so iTunes is launched to try and find it.

If you change the country in your URL to `au` then it shows the app information in Safari.

https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/muzeroom/id1331957823?ls=1&mt=8

Comment: Thank you!!!  Seems so obvious now.  I had just followed the link from iTunesConnect assuming it would be valid.  Regional differences makes perfect sense.